# Enviar variable por petición HTTP POST con Volley y recibir un texto plano de respuesta

Tags: java, php, android, android-volley

Estoy probando la librería **Volley** de Google para hacer **peticiones http** y lo que intento es lo siguiente: Desde una aplicación Android, quiero enviar una cadena de texto por **POST** a un **script PHP** que tengo corriendo en un servidor, cuando dicho script reciba esta petición me gustaría que devolviese un texto plano en un **header** para poder recogerlo desde la aplicación android.

Todo lo referente a la petición lo tengo implementado correctamente, mi problema viene al intentar obtener el texto plano que devuelve el script PHP, ya que cuando muestro la variable response del método **onResponse()**, esta solo me muestra el **código 200** (código para indicar que la petición se ha realizado correctamente), pero no obtengo el texto plano.

Mi código es el siguiente:

**Petición POST desde Android con Volley**

```
    try {
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            String URL = getResources().getString(R.string.url_web);
            JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
            jsonBody.put("username", username);
            final String mRequestBody = jsonBody.toString();

            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.i("LOG_VOLLEY", response);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("LOG_VOLLEY", error.toString());
                }
            }) {
                @Override
                public String getBodyContentType() {
                    return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
                }

                @Override
                public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                    try {
                        return mRequestBody == null ? null : mRequestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                        VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", mRequestBody, "utf-8");
                        return null;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                    String responseString = "";
                    if (response != null) {

                        responseString = String.valueOf(response.statusCode);

                    }
                    return Response.success(responseString, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));

                }
            };

            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Como podéis ver en el onResponse escribo en el log la respuesta con la siguiente línea:

```
 Log.i("LOG_VOLLEY", response);
```

Y en la consola muestra el código 200:

```
I/LOG_VOLLEY: 200
```

**Código del script PHP encargado de devolver la respuesta:**

```
<?php 

$name   = urldecode($_POST['username']);

if (isset($name)){
    $data = "Petición realizada con éxito";
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');
    echo $data;
}

?>
```

¿Como podría obtener desde la aplicación Android este texto plano?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que aquí:

```
 @Override
        protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
            String responseString = "";
            if (response != null) {
                //Das a responseString el valor del statusCode, o sea 200
                responseString = String.valueOf(response.statusCode);

            }
            return Response.success(responseString, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));

        }
    };
```

estás dando a `responseString` el valor del `statusCode`, el cual como ha sido exitoso es igual a 200. Debería ser:

```
                responseString = new String(response.data, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, al realizar los cambios que me has dicho, en el return me da el siguiente error: `Incompatible Types, Required: Response <String> , Found : Response <NetworkResponse>`

Comment: @Hechi Ufff, no uso volley de esa manera. Si cambias el return por esto: `return Response.success(response);`

Comment: Al final lo he solucionado cambiando el response string a esto: `responseString = new String(response.data, "UTF-8");` y efectivamente me devuelve lo que muestra el script PHP, pero en este caso en vez de devolver lo que yo esperaba me devuelve un error de php diciendo que el índice de la variable $_POST['username'] no está definido :( , aun así es un buen avance, si cambias el responseString en tu respuesta con el que te he puesto aquí te la doy por buena, muchas gracias.

Comment: @Hechi Me alegro. He modificado. De todos modos me gusta más usar Volley para post como se explica aquí en la opción 1: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40079812/5587982 . Es mucho más claro a la hora de recuperar el response.

Comment: Al final probé la opción 1 que aparece en dicho hilo y me ha funcionado de perlas. Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: @Hechi Me alegro. Esa forma es mucho más transparente a la hora de enviar los parámetros al servidor y a la hora de recuperar la respuesta. Supongo que ahora no te sale el error de undefined index, el cual venía sin duda porque había algún error en la forma de hacer el POST en el código anterior.  Saludos.